TypeScript / Type Narrowing (small issue)
I'm trying to implement a function that can take in an object, and without presuming what type it might be casts and returns the object to the correct type. The function cannot take in a type parameter (as that defeats the point). Is this possible in Typescript? See my attempt below.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// initial set up

enum Types {
  Type_A = 'Type_A',
  Type_B = 'Type_B',
}

interface A_DTO {
  type: Types.Type_A;
  commonProperty: string;
  uniquePropertyA: string;
}

interface B_DTO {
  type: Types.Type_B;
  commonProperty: string;
  uniquePropertyB: string;
}

type AnyDTO = A_DTO | B_DTO;

@Component({
  selector: 'cmp',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './cmp.component.html',
})
export class CmpComponent {
  protected readonly Types = Types;

  // create instances 

  aaa: AnyDTO = {
    type: this.Types.Type_A,
    commonProperty: 'commonProperty',
    uniquePropertyA: 'uniquePropertyA',
  };

  bbb: AnyDTO = {
    type: this.Types.Type_B,
    commonProperty: 'commonProperty',
    uniquePropertyB: 'uniquePropertyB',
  };

  // initial assignment 
  object = this.bbb;

  ngOnInit() {
 
    this.object

    // type function handler - CANNOT GET TO WORK 
    let variable = this.castObjectToType(this.object);
    // QUESTION IS... can this.castObjectToType do type narrowing in such a way that I can do this (if object is assigned as this.bbb initially)
    variable.uniqueProperty // cannot access properties - thought I might be able to access uniquePropertyB
    
  }


  // type A,B,C, etc. guard handler... CANNOT GET TO WORK
  private castObjectToType(object: AnyDTO): AnyDTO | undefined {
    if (object === undefined || !this.hasProperty(object, 'type') || !object.type) {
      return undefined;
    }
  
    switch (object.type) {
      case this.Types.Type_A:
        return object as A_DTO;
      case this.Types.Type_B:
        return object as B_DTO;
      default:
        return undefined;
    }
  }


  // helper function
  private hasProperty<Obj, Prop extends string>(
    obj: Obj,
    prop: Prop
  ): obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
  }


}

But am not sure why the casting doesn't work...(see stackblitz below)
Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6eped6?file=src%2Fcmp%2Fcmp.component.ts
Do I have to create a type guard function for each available type?

Please [edit] to make the code here a [mre], where you don't need to go to an external site to understand it. All of your values and types should be native to TS (or angular I guess) or you should define them in plaintext here. Whatever AnyDTO and A_DTO and B_DTO are should be present here, and ideally you'd make your code standalone and not an excerpt of some class. The goal for a [mre] is that others should be able to copy and paste into their own IDEs and immediately get to work on it, without needing to navigate away from Stack Overflow to do so.

copied full code here, so it can be followed

Is this approach what you're looking for? You're tying to "cast" something, so that's just a type assertion, right? If this is what you need I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] to clarify what you need, and you might consider removing the angular dependency from the question, since your problem has to do with TS and not angular, per se... a more streamlined [mre] without external dependencies would help. Let me know how you want to proceed.

Well, yes, sort of. I thought, instead of creating a type guard function for EACH type, like isTypeA( ), and isTypeB ( ), and passing that into an if ( ), where type narrowing could then occur in the if scope. I thought I could have one function, that I pass the object into, then that function returns the object of the appropriate type (not sure if possible), so I can then access the unique properties in that type. If I have 10 subclasses, I'd need to create a type assertion for each subclass. I looked at the link that says 'this approach' but couldn't run the code.

• "couldn't run the code"? It's a typing issue not a runtime issue, right? Copy it to your own IDE that has angular in there and run it, and get back to me, if you don't mind. But I really don't know anything about angular, so if that's important, maybe I should disengage to cut down on noise and let others help. • I don't see a type guard function for each type in my code, and not for your code either. You have one castObjectToType() which is doing an assertion. And you have one type guard function. I'm confused about what the issue is.

Thanks. Let me sort out my stackblitz. Give me 5 mins

ok - hoping the question is clearer. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6eped6?file=src%2Fcmp%2Fcmp.component.ts

@jcalz - your code hosted on typescript does work. But, it's not 'quite' what I was looking for, as you pass in B_DTO (so a presumption is already made about it's type)... I think this is a solution I could work with though. Thanks for your help

I think I understand even less now, since I'm not sure where the information about B_DTO would be coming from. Your example seems to intentionally throw away such information by annotating as AnyDTO. Where would the information come from? Runtime? But TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime. I could write up my suggestion as an answer if you want, but I still don't get what you're trying to do.

I think I need to use separate type guard functions. For further clarity, I was hoping castObjectToType to cast this.object to type B_DTO, so when it is assigned to 'variable', I could read the property variable.uniquePropertyB. But, it seems like its not possible.

I think I need to disengage because I'm understanding less as time goes on. You should be able to write a single type guard function and call it different ways. If you're saying you want to call a single function a single way and somehow it has different outputs, then I'm very confused about what that could mean. In some sense it looks like you're asking "could I have code like const x: unknown = {a: ""}; magic(x); x.a; where magic(x) somehow retrieves the property a from x even though you've thrown away that info by annotating as unknown. I don't get it, sorry.

Dude, I think you need to disengage! (but thanks for being responsive)
